# How can I retrieve all values ​in a list?

Tags: list, kotlin, android-recyclerview

```
    data class ThingsRs(
        @SerializedName("code")
        val code: String,
        @SerializedName("data")
        val `data`: Data,
        @SerializedName("result")
        val result: String
    ) : Parcelable {
        @Parcelize
        data class Data(
            @SerializedName("aList")
            val aList: List<a>,
            @SerializedName("other")
            val patrolNum: Int
        ) : Parcelable {
            @Parcelize
            data class a(
                @SerializedName("aId")
                val aId: String,
                @SerializedName("aName")
                val aName: String,
                @SerializedName("cList")
                val cList: List<C>
            ) : Parcelable {
                @Parcelize
                data class C(
                    @SerializedName("cId")
                    val checkId: String,
                    @SerializedName("cName")
                    var cName: String
                ) : Parcelable
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to get only the values ​​of cName from the data model above and show it in the recyclerview, but if I use get() from an array,
I get it as datas.aList.get(0).cName. Then I get only the cName of the first array.
one?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. It's up to you to decide what information you want to show in your RecyclerView. If an inner list has multiple values that you need to show, then you need to define a view layout that can show multiple values for each item. By the way, you don't need `@SerializedName` when the name is exactly the same as the property name.

Comment: I want to show the values ​​of cName in that data list, but I can only access one value of cName, so I am fetching only one value, not multiple values.

Comment: Why do you say you can access only one value? You are using the `cList` to get the first value out of it, so you already have all of them in the `cList`.

Comment: datas.aList.get(0).cName because this will only get the cName of the 0th array

Comment: `cName` is not a property of your `a` class. Do you mean to use `datas.aList.get(0).cList`? I think your code would be a lot easier to follow if you don't nest the class definitions inside each other and you use proper names for each class (a word starting with a capital letter).

Comment: Oh, are you simply asking how to turn all items of a list into a single String?

Comment: The data class cannot be modified because the data is received and used.

Comment: Data will come in several times according to the format of that data class, but the problem is that only the first cName that comes in is called when accessed through get(0).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean that you have a `Data` (or `ThingsRs`) object and you would like to extract all `cName` properties of all `C` objects stored in all `a` objects, then you can do it like this:

```kotlin
val cNames = data.aList.asSequence()
    .flatMap { it.cList }
    .map { it.cName }
    .toList()
```

First, [flatMap()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/flat-map.html) is used to convert a sequence of `a` objects into a sequence of all `C` objects. Then [map()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/map.html) is used to extract `cName` properties of all `C` objects.

`asSequence()` (and `toList()`) is optional. It makes all calculations lazy, so we don't actually create a full list of all `C` objects, but rather create a list of `cName` values while iterating over both `aList` and `cList`.